# Cannot access usb webcam through OpenCV, Cygwin

Tags: opencv, cygwin, usb

I've downloaded and installed cygwin for windows, I downloaded opencv (ported version for cygwin) and installed it successfully and my code compiles.

The problem I have is that `CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(-1);` is always null!

The usb webcam is connected and is not in use.
Why I can't access my webcam in cygwin? (Is there any particular reason like for example I should mount the device first, If this is the case I have no knowledge about it)

Please advice