# Listing camera devices with python

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, analog-digital-converter

I will be needing to capture a video stream from an analog connection (RS-232, S-video, or composite) to process it in OpenCV. Is it possible to get a list of available such cameras with python? It seems the [videocapture](http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/) lib can list available devices, but I am not sure if that includes devices **connected through other means than usb**. As of 2011 at least, it would seem such a functionality is not included natively in OpenCV (reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8046886/2322456)).
Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044539/listing-available-devices-in-python-opencv seems to work with some non-USB cameras.